# Running multiple compute kernels concurrently in Metal

Tags: ios, macos, metal

(How) can I run multiple compute kernels concurrently in Metal (I don't necessarily need them to run in parallel at the exact same time, concurrent execution is sufficient)?

Are `MTLCommandBuffer`s in 2 different `MTLCommandQueue`s (on the same device) executed concurrently or not (ie. do queues behave like CUDA streams?)?

*Note: I cannot further split the kernels into smaller subkernels.*

Comment: I don't think you can. As far as I know the GPU always executes only one kernel at a time. Of course, inside that kernel things can (and should) be done in parallel. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans Hi, I need to implement some kind of QoS (similar to `DispatchQueue` QoSes in GCD), so that I can have a background-priority compute kernel running and in case of demand (eg. when an external event fires (either via network, user interaction, etc.)) I can dispatch very-high-priority compute task, meaning the background-priority computation can be paused until the top-priority one has finished (like interrupts). (I imagine there could be one StreamingMultiprocessor left available for the high-priority tasks and the rest could preform the background tasks.)

Comment: There is no such thing as a background-priority compute kernel. A compute kernel is only supposed to run for a short time (it gets killed if it takes more than 10 seconds but certain operations get killed way faster than that, for example I've found that if a loop takes more than 0.5 seconds the GPU kills the job). So if you want a kernel to run all the time (to process video frames, for example) you'll have to schedule it yourself on a timer or something. And so if a high priority job comes in you schedule that kernel instead of the low-priority one.

Comment: I was thinking about a similar approach; a scheduler that would granularize all kernels submitted to it into dispatches of only a few threadgroups of a kernel at a time, thus giving the possibility of explicitly interleaving the jobs. The problem with this approach is that I don't know how long does it take for a single dispatched subproblem to complete (ie. I don't have any upper-time limit on the execution time of a subproblem), which would mean I cannot assure that the top-priority task is scheduled **immediately** after being submitted. I'll just accept this cannot be done in Metal now.